# Determine if class has changed (not object)

Tags: c#, class, caching, hash

Is there any way to determine if code building up a class has been changed? Like retrieving a hash of some sort of its content.

I have a lot of classes that are used for generating text files.
Currently I am trying to figure out a way for the program in runtime to determine if someone has changed the class in any way since the last generation (thus knowing if the files needs to be generated again or can be leaved as they are).

Example:

- Someone uses the program and generates a lot of files. A cache is built up and saved as a file containing cache information for each class generating a file.
- Someone uses the program a few days later and nothing has changed, so the cache determines for each file that they does not have to be regenerated.
- Someone changes one of the classes a bit so its output should become slightly different.
- The next time someone uses the program to generate those particular files created by the changed class should be regenerated.

I'm aware that I could use some sort of incrementing version solution, but I really want it to be more clever than that. I would need this to work even when just debugging in Visual Studio.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a timestamp on the class files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate checksums of your classes files (using md5, sha1, sha2 or whatever you like), store them somewhere and regenerate your classes if checksums not matches.

All mentioned algorithms are actually crypto-hashes, so they are strongly collision-resistant. Thus chance of accidental checksum mismatch is very low.